# Error when register provider Zend in Netbeans 6.9

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I install :

- netbeans 6.9 on 'C:\Program
  Files\NetBeans 6.9'
- xampp 1.7.2 on D:\xampp
- i have upgrade zend through pear

I follow the screencast and when clicking the Register Provider button. But I get message like this:

on create config tab

```
Successfully written Zend Tool config.
It is located at: \Documents and Settings\Permana/.zf.ini
```

on enable.config.provider NetbeansCommandsProvider

```
                        User has no config file.                        
                          An Error Has Occurred                         
 Client has no persistent configuration.                                

Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.10.7
Details for action "Enable" and provider "Config"
    zf enable config.manifest class-name
    zf enable config.provider class-name
```

And of course because of this error I cannot create zend project using netbeans. Did anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: the problem was solved: I just download the Zend framework minimal, extract and copy bin/zf.php to D:\xampp\php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday I had the same problema. I wrote a post in my blog:

http://otroblogmas.com/error-zend-tool-netbeanscommandsprovider-php/

I found two solutions: either **modify the file *zf.ini*** in your profile, or **copy the file *NetBeansCommandsProvider.php*** in a path of include_path.

Comment: thank you for the reply Ian. Yes, that can be a solution too.

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP:

Make sure the environment variable ZF_HOME is set.

Comment: Struggled to register zend on windows xp until i added the zf_home environment variable. Thanks a lot. Really helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I found the soltution to this problem. Just delete the /home/username/.zf.ini and go to netbeans and register zendframework provider again. This will generate zf.ini file in your home directory with new path.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 10.10, NetBeans 6.9.1, Zend Framework 1.11**

**Reconfigurar**

Edit **PHP.ini** 
include_path = ".:/opt/lampp/etc/library" ; Files "/opt/lampp/etc/library/Zend"

**gedit /etc/profile**

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin # Includer zf.php and zf.sh

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/etc/library

**Remove** zf.ini and register NetBeans provider again *(from Tools > Options > PHP > Zend)*.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct, however in my case there was no zf.ini file under my user directory (using Windows 7). In that case you need to run two commands:

```
zf --setup storage-directory
zf --setup config-file
```

That will create your zf.ini file and the storage directory under your user directory. Source: [here](http://blog.calevans.com/2010/02/23/how-i-got-zend_tool-working-on-windows/)